# FCK-Editor set image path in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, fckeditor

trying to set the default image-path of the FCK-Editor in DotNetNuke..?!

any ideas?

Best Regards
RL

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by performing the following actions:

1. Log in to DNN and go to any Text/HTML module's **Edit Text** page.
2. Below the editor, click the **Show custom editor options** link.
3. For the **Settings Type** field, click the **Portal** radio button.
4. Under the **Other editor options** section, for the **Image Folder** field, select the image folder you'd like it to use as the default image folder.
5. For the **Apply custom settings to** field, click the **Portal** option.
6. Click the **Apply** link to apply the changes.
7. Click the **Close** link to close the options window.